# OpenMP what does printing _OPENMP means

Tags: openmp

I faced with following part of OpenMP program:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
    std::cout << _OPENMP << '\n';
#endif
```

What does it do? And why we use `#ifdef` and `#endif`.

Comment: Please note that I removed your secondary question / rant as it is off-topic for SO and you generally want to only ask one question in each question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's prints the version. This is well documented in the standard itself:

> In implementations that support a preprocessor, the `_OPENMP` macro name is defined to
>   have the decimal value *yyyymm* where *yyyy* and *mm* are the year and month designations
>   of the version of the OpenMP API that the implementation supports.

The macro needs to be checked with `#ifdef`, otherwise the code would not compile without OpenMP.